# BaseAdapter NotifyDatasetChanged() getView() Not Working

Tags: android

I have `BaseAdapter` Class for `ListView` in my Custom `ListView` Project. Now I I have `TextView`, and Tow Image Buttons(Edit and Delete) are in my `listView` row. When I am fire delete query From GetView() And call `notifyDataSetChanged();` but nothing happening there. Please See below code :

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parentView) {

```
    ViewHolder holder ; 
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.local_jobs_list_row , null);

    holder.job_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_job_name);
    holder.img_edit = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon_edit_job);
    holder.img_delete = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon_delete_job);

    convertView.setTag(holder);

    holder.img_delete.setTag(itemDetailsrrayList.get(position).getLocal_job_id());
    holder.img_delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View v) {

            db.open();
            db.deleteLocalJob(String.valueOf(v.getTag()));
            db.close();
            notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    });

    holder.job_name.setText(itemDetailsrrayList.get(position).getLocal_job_name());


    return convertView;
}
```

Here `notifyDatasetChanged()` not working ......please anybody tell me where i am making mistack ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`notifyDatasetChanged()` will work when you do a modification in `itemDetailsrrayList`. You are doing only Database operation not removing item from ArrayList.Remove the item from ArrayList as well. It will work.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure `BaseAdapter` methods

```
registerDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) 
unregisterDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer)
```

are not overridden.

Comment: can you make some explanation and method, how to use it ?